# bash column command confused by ANSI color escapes

Tags: bash, centos, cygwin

I have a bash script I got from [Gary Bernhardt's dotfiles](https://github.com/garybernhardt/dotfiles) that prints a nice colorized listing of the recent git commits. It uses the `column` command to line the output up into columns. On my Mac, it works wonderfully.

Strangely however, when I run it on Cygwin or CentOS 6, the column bit doesn't work. All the fields have three spaces between them, regardless of their length, producing jagged gutters between "columns". I've narrowed it down to the ANSI color escape codes. If I remove those, the columns come out lined up.

The zsh version is the same on all three (and the problem appears exactly the same way in bash). I can't tell what the version of `column` is, but they look exactly the same and their man pages are the same for whatever that's worth.

Why would this work on my Mac but not on the other OS'es?

Comment: Do you have the same escape codes in the OSX version?

Comment: @terdon: Yep, it's exactly the same code on all the systems; it uses the standard ANSI color escape sequences and the color comes out right on all the systems. Only the alignment is different. Code is here: https://github.com/scanny/dotfiles/blob/master/link/.githelpers#L52  One odd thing is that the escape codes are exactly the same length in every position in every row. So even if it was including them in character counts it wouldn't throw off the alignment.

Comment: Having the same issue here.. would love to have this log format with nice columns, but bash does not like it for some reason...

Comment: forgot to mention, I'm on arch with bash 4.2.045-5

Comment: Hah, I'm here in 2021 with the same question…because I'm also still using Gary's `.githelpers`. :D

Comment: What bash version do you run on the Mac? Make sure that you have the same version, lest you compare apple with pears.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the next version v2.40 of [util-linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux) / [column](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html) will handle text containing [Fe Escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Fe_Escape_sequences) from [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) properly.

With [this change](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/pull/2767), programs that output text with ANSI sequences will be handled correctly as in this example:

```bash
$ tput cols
108

$ echo BEFORE; ls -1 --sort=time --color=always | head -n 19 | column
BEFORE
column-test.sh  test_enosys             test_pathnames
column-pr.md                    test_mkfds              test_sha1
tests                   test_uuid_namespace     lib
ansiescape-test.txt             test_tiocsti            test_md5
column                  test_sigreceive         test_byteswap
text-utils              test_sysinfo
column-old.c                    test_strerror

$ echo REFERENCE; ls -1 --sort=time --color=never | head -n 19 | column
REFERENCE
column-test.sh          text-utils              test_tiocsti            test_sha1
column-pr.md            column-old.c            test_sigreceive         lib
tests                   test_enosys             test_sysinfo            test_md5
ansiescape-test.txt     test_mkfds              test_strerror           test_byteswap
column                  test_uuid_namespace     test_pathnames

$ echo AFTER; ls -1 --sort=time --color=always | head -n 19 | column
AFTER
column-test.sh          text-utils              test_tiocsti            test_sha1
column-pr.md            column-old.c            test_sigreceive         lib
tests                   test_enosys             test_sysinfo            test_md5
ansiescape-test.txt     test_mkfds              test_strerror           test_byteswap
column                  test_uuid_namespace     test_pathnames
```

Answer (score 1):

`column` works on a per-character basis. It counts printable characters of each cells and then pads to align them (see [code sources](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/text-utils/column.c?h=v2.29#n88) for v2.29).

The problem you are facing is that your stream contains non-printable [ANSI escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) embedding printable characters. `column` then fails to compute the real cell minimal width of those cells and misaligns next cells of the same row.

---

Here is an example with the blue color code `<esc>[34m` for the `A` cell, using column v2.29:

```
$ echo '\033[34mA\033[0m B\nC D'|column -t
A  B
C         D
```

`A` cell is seen as a height printable-character long since only both escape characters are detected as non-printable.
Hence C column is given seven unwanted padding spaces.

---

Note that this behavior is not consistent across releases of column. Version 2.26 uses [`wcswidth`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wcswidth.3.html) to compute cells visible width and leads to a different mis-alignment.

Comment: This is really useful insight @A. Is there anything to be done about it in this case, like using an alternative command/approach? or is it just a limit of what can be done with what the command shell has to offer?

Comment: I don't know about a command-line `column`-like tool aware of various escape sequences and other special characters, but it is always possible to create one. It may not be as easy as simply counting cell width well. For example such tool may need to know about background color codes to terminate and re-open them between cells. It must also skip separators found in those sequences to not alter them.

Comment: One way to workaround misalignments is to insert backspaces `\010` at the beginning of each misaligned cell. So seven times at the beginning of the D cell in my example: `echo '\033[34mA\033[0m B\nC \010\010\010\010\010\010\010D'|column -t`.

Comment: Note that in git log format syntax, you should be able to encode backslash this way: `%x08`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that comes here and it is interested to having a `column`-like output but with **color codes** and **ANSI** escape sequences, i made a version that has the **same syntax** as `column` (for the supported flags) and it renders the **output as expected**.

I found various solutions online, but they all used `Bash` for looping, which is very slow compared to **`Perl`**, which i used.

You can find the script **[here](https://github.com/LukeSavefrogs/column_ansi)**.

It can be executed directly (`./column_ansi.sh [--options]`) or sourced (`source ./column_ansi.sh`, in which case the command will be available as `column_ansi`)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the `column` command looks at `$TERM` and/or `$LANG` to see what (if anything) constitutes a colour-code.

Of course, you could just use `git log --pretty=format:...` to output a column-aligned colour-coded log to begin with. For example, I use `git hist` and have this in my `~/.git/config`:

```
[alias]
   hist = log --pretty=format:\"           \t%C(yellow)%h %C(red)%ad %C(cyan)%aN%C(reset)   \t| %s%C(blue)%d%C(reset)\" --graph --date=short
```